# how to post a new feed on wall like facebook

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3, nsjsonserialization

Am a newbie in swift, am trying to post a new feed on user's wall like facebook, but my api response is displaying nil in console, and it works fine in web, any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```
    @IBAction func upload(_ sender: AnyObject) {
             let user = UserManager.getLoggedInUser()!
             let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:NSURL(string: "http://www.MYAPI")!as URL)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let PostUtctime = DateFormatter()
            PostUtctime.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'To'HH:mm:ss"
            let str: String = PostUtctime.string(from: Date())
            print("Date = \(str)")

let guidMemberID = user.userID
            print(guidMemberID)
            let paramToSend =  "{\"guidMemberID\":\"\(user.userID)\", \"ImageString\": \", \"strAboutFeed\":\"\(textView.text)\", \"PostUtctime\": \"\(PostUtctime)\"}"
```

*API normally responds after the above line execution saying its posted successfully or there's been an error*

```
             print(textView.text as Any)
            request.httpBody = (paramToSend as AnyObject) as? Data
            session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,completionHandler: {

(data, response, error) -> Void in
             guard let _:Data = data
                        else {
                    print(response as Any)
                    return
                    }
                     var json: [String:AnyObject]
                     do {

json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary as! [String : AnyObject]
                         print(json)
                        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                            // check for http errors
                            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                        }

let responseDataDictionary: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                        print(responseDataDictionary)
                                }
                    catch {
                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
            }).resume()
        }

}
```

*This is, if there's an error part of the code, Thank you for the time.*

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more info rather than just pasting a large code snippet and saying something is nil in there.  What exactly is nil? Provide a specific line. Also, Maybe annotate that code better so we can both understand what you're trying to do as well as have a bit more help figuring out what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JakeT. Am trying to post a feed on wall from the current logged in user from **UserManager class** Hope this suffices, if not i will give out more info, thanks